# How to select multiple values in a subquery but have each value assigned to matching parent select value?

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

Sorry for the wordy mess of a question. I have a query that draws data from the *User* table and I want to pull the *completionstate* from the *course_modules_completion* table for each activity in a course per user and course. I'm having trouble linking multiple values from various tables to a user per row.

I was able to obtain the info I wanted from the *User* table just fine. I then join multiple tables in order to be able to pull the completionstate field from the course_modules_completion table. What I need to do is pull the value of *completionstate* corresponding to each activity in a course for every user.

```
SELECT u.username AS 'ID'
,u.firstname AS 'Names'
,u.lastname AS 'Lastnames'

,(SELECT completionstate FROM prefix_course_modules_completion cmc
  INNER JOIN prefix_user u ON cmc.userid = u.id
  INNER JOIN prefix_course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id
  INNER JOIN prefix_course c ON cm.course = c.id
  INNER JOIN prefix_resource r ON c.id = r.course
  WHERE (r.id = 6) AND (c.id = 5)
) AS 'Activity 1'

FROM prefix_user u LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_grades g ON u.id = g.userid
INNER JOIN prefix_course_modules_completion cmc ON cmc.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN prefix_course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id
INNER JOIN prefix_course c ON cm.course = c.id
INNER JOIN prefix_resource r ON c.id = r.course

WHERE (u.id > 7) AND (u.firstaccess > 0) AND (c.id = 5)                                     

GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY u.firstname ASC
```

What I expected was something like this:

```
ID  - Name - Last name - Email   -  Activity 1 - Activity 2 - Test
382 - John - Johnson   - email@e.com  - Seen  -  Not seen  -  Failed
17  - Mark - Markson   - email2@e.com - Seen  -    Seen    -  Passed
```

Instead what I'm getting are multiple rows of the same user with the values wanted or the same value wanted for all users as if it wasn't making any distinction about the user. As you can see in the code above, I tried with a subquery just for the *completionstate* value but it's returning multiple rows and thus, an error.

Furthermore, I want to show the values from the *completionstate* column as text. There are four values in that column: 0, 1, 2, 3 and what I'd like to do is transform each into "Not seen", "Seen", "Completed and passed" and "Completed and failed" respectively.

Because I'm a beginner in SQL I'm having trouble identifying if my issues are because of bad logic, bad coding or both.

Edit: Pruned the code a little to make it simpler for this question.

Comment: Simplify the problem, take a look at  [mcve], and it will be easier to assist you.

Comment: The subqueries need to be correlated with the main query so they show the values for the same user.

Comment: You can use the `ELT()` function to turn a number into a string: `ELT(completion_state+1, 'Not seen', 'Seen', 'Completed and passed', 'Completed and failed')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a kind of pivot, so you can do it without the correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT u.username AS 'ID'
        ,u.firstname AS 'Names'
        ,u.lastname AS 'Lastnames'
        ,u.email AS 'Email'
        ,c.fullname AS 'Course'
        ,(LEFT(g.finalgrade,2)) AS 'Final grade'
        ,ELT(MAX(IF(r.id = 6, completion_state, NULL))+1,
            'Not seen', 'Seen', 'Completed and passed', 'Completed and failed') AS `Activity 1`
        ,ELT(MAX(IF(r.id = 7, completion_state, NULL))+1,
            'Not seen', 'Seen', 'Completed and passed', 'Completed and failed') AS `Activity 2`
        ,ELT(MAX(IF(r.id = 8, completion_state, NULL))+1,
            'Not seen', 'Seen', 'Completed and passed', 'Completed and failed') AS `Activity 3`
FROM prefix_user u LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_grades g ON u.id = g.userid
INNER JOIN prefix_course_modules_completion cmc ON cmc.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN prefix_course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id
INNER JOIN prefix_course c ON cm.course = c.id
INNER JOIN prefix_resource r ON c.id = r.course

WHERE (u.id > 7) AND (u.firstaccess > 0) AND (c.id = 5)                                     

GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.firstname ASC
```

Yuo should also group by `u.id` rather than `u.username`. This will allow you to select other columns that are functionally dependent on this primary key without using aggregation functions.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, Barmar. I did look into pivoting tables but I couldn't wrap my head around it. I'm trying to run the code you provided but the part with ELT is giving me an 'Error reading from database' error.

Comment: I took another look at the code you provided, Barmar, and it worked after all, seems like an error on my end. I want to say thank you for the help and support! I had no idea ELT existed or how to properly pivot rows to columns, thanks!